# jQuery: Selecting immediate siblings

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this HTML:

```
<div id="Wrapper">

  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>
  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>

  <div class="MyBorder"></div>

  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>
  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>
  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>

  <div class="MyBorder"></div>

  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>
  <div class="MyClass">some text</div>

</div>
```

I want to get the text of the MyClass divs next to the one clicked on, in the order they're in.

This is what I have:

```
$('#Wrapper').find('.MyClass').each(function () {
  AddressString = AddressString + "+" + $(this).text();
});
```

I know adds ALL the MyClass divs; I'm just wondering if there's a quick way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: the next and previous ? or the ones between the `myborder` elements

Comment: You can use `.siblings()` to return *brother* elements.

Comment: Could you put some different text in your elements, and then demonstrate what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text), [.prevUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil) and [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil)**

To get text of all previous and next `.MyClass` element from clicked `.MyBorder`:

```
$('#Wrapper').on('click', '.MyBorder', function() {
  var AddressString = [];
  $(this).nextUntil('.MyBorder').text(function(index, text) {
       AddressString.push(text);
  });

  $(this).prevUntil('.MyBorder').text(function(index, text) {
       AddressString.push(text);
  });
  console.log(AddressString.join(', '));
});
```

Combination of `prevUntil()`, `nextUntil()` with **[siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)**

```
$('#Wrapper').on('click', '.MyClass' function() {
    var AddressString = [];
    $(this).siblings('.MyClass').prevUntil('.MyBorder').add($(this).prevUntil('.MyBorder')).text(function(index, text) {
        AddressString.push(text);
    });
    console.log(AddressString.join(', '));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [`.prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

```
$('#Wrapper').on('click','.MyClass', function(e){
    var self = $(this),
        previous = self.prevUntil('.MyBorder', '.MyClass'), // find the previous ones
        next = self.nextUntil('.MyBorder', '.MyClass'), // find the next ones
        all = $().add(previous).add(self).add(next); // combine them in order

    var AddressString = '';

    all.each(function(){
        AddressString += '+' + $(this).text();
    });

    alert(AddressString);

});
```

This will find all the `.MyClass` elements (*in order*) that lie in the same group of `.MyClass` elements seperated by the `.MyBorder` elements.

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kLzPs/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to get all siblings that are within the borders, the following works:

```
$("#Wrapper").on("click", ".MyClass", function(){
    var strings = [];
    $(this)
        .add( $(this).prevUntil(".MyBorder") )
        .add( $(this).nextUntil(".MyBorder") )
        .text(function(i,t){
            strings.push( t );
        });
    alert( strings.join(', ') );
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uw5uP/3/